# How can I animate multiple buttons with StoryBoard without the animation applying to all buttons simultaneously? (WPF C# .NET Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a button change color when I hover my mouse on it and when I left click it. It's all done, however when I hover/click one button, every button animates, but I only want the one that I hovered/clicked to animate. I also want to define it in style.

Code:

```
        <Style x:Key="Button21.8.1Rev4" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="8" Background="{DynamicResource SystemAltMediumHighColorBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource SystemAltHighColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumHighColor}" To="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" SpeedRatio="8" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" To="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumHighColor}" SpeedRatio="8" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" To="{StaticResource SystemBaseMediumColor}" SpeedRatio="8" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="{StaticResource SystemBaseMediumColor}" To="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" SpeedRatio="8" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: You are animating the Color property of the resource Button.Static.Background, i.e. a single Brush instance that is used for all Buttons. Change the Setter so that it assigns a new SolidColorBrush like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64705642/1136211

Comment: How do I go about doing that considering that it's a button style? What and where do I put things?

Comment: See the link to the answer.

Comment: I did see it, but I couldn't make much of it, sorry. I just don't know how to change the setter.